# Function that handles either an Array<T> or IntArray

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to create a generic function that takes either an `Array<T>` or `IntArray` and iterates over them and performs an arbitrary operation. Unfortunately, `IntArray` is not a sub-type of `Array<T>`. Is this possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Such a function already exists: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not directly possible, because `IntArray` is a separate type that has no relations with `Array<T>` that could allow a single function to handle both.

You can, however, define an overload that converts an `IntArray` into an `Array<Int>` or provide a different, optimized implementation:

```
fun <T> foo(items: Array<T>) { /* ... */ }

fun <T> foo(items: IntArray) = foo(items.toTypedArray())
```

<sup>See: [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html)</sup>

As you can see in the `kotlin-stdlib` docs, many functions are separately defined in this way for both `Array<T>` and various primitive array types (though with separate implementations, which is more efficient than converting an array), e.g. [`.forEach { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html), [`.toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html).